# android background task to check tcp server

Tags: android

I created an android application, I want the application to check the server continuously even when its activities not showing/running (i mean in background). So i decided to use `foreground` but i noticed that as of android 8 it need notification and an icon on it. I don't want the icon on notification-bar when it's checking server; I want it to act like `whatsApp` that continuously check its server for new message and never show any icon during checking the server. 
 
 What do you suggest?

Comment: You can't do that. And how do you know `Whatsapp` works like this?

Comment: i don't know how whatsApp works? do you know?

Comment: So how whatsApp checks the server for new messages?

Comment: They simply don't. You can use FCM for that. Use your own server to send a notification to the android device.